# Getting the Logical File Name using RESTORE FILELISTONLY from a DB backup and storing it into a variable

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ps, sqlps

I am using a fairly simple PowerShell script to automate the process of restoring databases:

```
    #Script to restore database.
    $serverInstance = $args[0]
    $dbName = $args[1]
    $file = $args[2]
    $dataDestination = $args[3]
    $logDestination = $args[4]

    Import-Module sqlps

    $relocateData = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile(###LOGICALFILENAME###, $dataDestination)
    $relocateLog = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile(###LOGICALFILENAME###, $logDestination)

    Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $dbName -BackupFile $file -RelocateFile @($relocateData,$relocateLog)
```

I am looking for a way to dynamically fetch the logical file names of the files contained in a database backup ($file) and store them into a variable so the can be renamed accordingly.

Anyone have any ideas? I've been banging my head against this for way too long! :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try checking Dbatools `https://docs.dbatools.io/#Restore-DbaDatabase`

Answer (score 4):

As always with Powershell and SQL Server [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) is your friend.  It returns a DataTable that's simple to navigate.  EG

```
$dt = Invoke-Sqlcmd "restore filelistonly from disk='c:\temp\aw.bak'"

$dataFileLogicalName = ""
$logFileLogicalName = ""
foreach ($r in $dt)
{
  if ($r.Type -eq "L")
  {
    $logFileLogicalName = $r.LogicalName
  }
  if ($r.Type -eq "D")
  {
    $dataFileLogicalName = $r.LogicalName
  }
  write-host "$($r.Type) $($r.LogicalName)  $($r.PhysicalName)"
}

write-host "data=$dataFileLogicalName  log=$logFileLogicalName"
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Finally got it working with your help!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was getting a similar error. But in my case I was not using PowerShell, but running it in SSMS.

[image: RESTORE in SSMS]

So the steps to the issue and also how to fix are as follows.

First I downloaded the WideWorldImporters-Standard.bak file [from releases here](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/wide-world-importers-v1.0).

Now I run the following command in SSMS in an attemp to restore it.

```
RESTORE DATABASE WideWorldImporters FROM DISK = N'C:\Users\msi\Downloads\WideWorldImporters-Standard.bak'
```

This gives the following errors.

```
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Directory lookup for the file "D:\Data\WideWorldImporters.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
File 'WWI_Primary' cannot be restored to 'D:\Data\WideWorldImporters.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Directory lookup for the file "D:\Data\WideWorldImporters_UserData.ndf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
File 'WWI_UserData' cannot be restored to 'D:\Data\WideWorldImporters_UserData.ndf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Directory lookup for the file "E:\Log\WideWorldImporters.ldf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
File 'WWI_Log' cannot be restored to 'E:\Log\WideWorldImporters.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

So now I change the command to include the mdf and ldf file paths as follows.

```
RESTORE DATABASE WideWorldImporters FROM DISK = N'C:\Users\msi\Downloads\WideWorldImporters-Standard.bak' WITH 
    MOVE 'WideWorldImporters' TO 'C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\WideWorldImporters.mdf'
    , 
    MOVE 'WideWorldImporters_Log' TO 'C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\WideWorldImporters_Log.ldf'
```

Now this gives me the error in question as follows.

```
Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Logical file 'WideWorldImporters' is not part of database 'WideWorldImporters'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Now I run the RESTORE FILELISTONLY command as suggested to get the list as follows.

This shows me the files along with path as follows.

```
LogicalName                                                                                                                      PhysicalName                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     Type FileGroupName                                                                                                                    Size                 MaxSize              FileId               CreateLSN                               DropLSN                                 UniqueId                             ReadOnlyLSN                             ReadWriteLSN                            BackupSizeInBytes    SourceBlockSize FileGroupId LogGroupGUID                         DifferentialBaseLSN                     DifferentialBaseGUID                 IsReadOnly IsPresent TDEThumbprint                              SnapshotUrl
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- -------------------- --------------- ----------- ------------------------------------ --------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ---------- --------- ------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WWI_Primary                                                                                                                      D:\Data\WideWorldImporters.mdf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   D    PRIMARY                                                                                                                          1073741824           35184372080640       1                    0                                       0                                       8D30F4F9-A463-404F-805A-9BD1C634B66B 0                                       0                                       11730944             512             1           NULL                                 623000001720300037                      C6D12B8E-E389-4961-ADD4-FE6E468F4E44 0          1         NULL                                       NULL
WWI_UserData                                                                                                                     D:\Data\WideWorldImporters_UserData.ndf                                                                                                                                                                                                                          D    USERDATA                                                                                                                         2147483648           35184372080640       3                    37000000095200001                       0                                       28D406E0-78FF-4400-9A4B-3A05D136B1F3 0                                       0                                       580124672            512             2           NULL                                 623000001720300037                      C6D12B8E-E389-4961-ADD4-FE6E468F4E44 0          1         NULL                                       NULL
WWI_Log                                                                                                                          E:\Log\WideWorldImporters.ldf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    L    NULL                                                                                                                             104857600            2199023255552        2                    0                                       0                                       6AC6807E-8774-415B-8EFC-E8C569B0855E 0                                       0                                       0                    512             0           NULL                                 0                                       00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 0          1         NULL                                       NULL

(3 rows affected)

Completion time: 2022-08-28T15:36:18.5341906+05:30
```

Now after taking note of the output, I modify the RESTORE Command to include all of the required files and paths as follows. This finally works.

```
RESTORE DATABASE WideWorldImporters FROM DISK = N'C:\Users\msi\Downloads\WideWorldImporters-Standard.bak' WITH 
MOVE 'WWI_Primary' TO 'C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\WideWorldImporters.mdf'
, MOVE 'WWI_Log' TO 'C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\WideWorldImporters_Log.ldf'
, MOVE 'WWI_UserData'  TO 'C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\WideWorldImporters_UserData.ndf'
```